# Zustandspassiv vs Perfekt Aktiv

Tags: grammar-identification

Das Zustandspassiv (also sein + Part. II, beispielsweise "Die Wäsche ist gewaschen") hat ja eine sehr ähnliche Bildungsform wie das Perfekt, zumindest falls letzteres mit "sein" gebildet wird.

Nun bin ich in einem B2-Buch auf eine Übung gestoßen, bei der man Zustandspassive finden sollte; laut Lösung ist eines davon:

"Die Frau beschwerte sich, dass beim Spülen so viel Geschirr zerbrochen ist."

Meines Erachtens sollte das aber aus Tempusgründen nicht die Passivform von "zerbrechen + Akk." (i.e. kaputt machen) sondern die Perfektform von "zerbrechen (intrans.)" (i.e. entzwei gehen) sein.

Hat sich da ein Fehler in die Lösung eingeschlichen oder bin ich auf der falschen Fährte?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Du hast Recht!

Begründung: "**Beim** Spülen" weist darauf hin, dass wir noch in der Handlung sind. Und während dieser Handlung führte das Geschirr seinerseits eine **aktive** Handlung aus:

> "das Geschirr ist entzwei gegangen" oder eben "das Geschirr ist zerbrochen".

Wenn das Geschirr während des Spülens im **Passiv** stehen soll, müsste es heißen:

> "das Geschirr wurde (vom Spülenden) zerbrochen".

Das **Zustandspassiv**

> "das Geschirr ist zerbrochen"

kann erst **nach dem Spülen** gelten, also etwa

> "Die Frau beschwerte sich, dass nach dem Spülen immer so viel Geschirr zerbrochen ist."